# Efficient way of writing subquery join statement in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have a `reviews` table like the one below:

[image]

A user can up vote or down vote these reviews. For which, I am maintaining another table named `review_counts`. It looks like the one below:

[image]

Here, `1` means up vote and `-1` is down vote.

Now, I am joining these two tables such that I will get reviews with total number of up vote counts and down vote counts all together. To achieve this, I have written the below query which is working fine.

```
 SELECT * FROM `reviews` as x 
 LEFT JOIN 
 (SELECT count(votes) as vote_up, review_id FROM `review_counts` WHERE votes = 1) as y ON x.review_id = y.review_id
 LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT count(votes) as vote_down, review_id FROM `review_counts` WHERE votes = -1) as z ON x.review_id = z.review_id
```

For which, I get the result like this:

[image]
Now, the question is that I am using two JOINS on same table to get the vote up and vote down, Is there any other way through which I can achieve similar results using single join statement?

Comment: Use `case` statement .

Comment: why did you tag it sql-server?

Comment: @sebas because i thought join statements exist in sql server too, so if somebody with similar knowledge can help me out.

Comment: @Immu: I suggest you remove your answer and instead comment on mine. Surely, your answer will be flagged.

Comment: @symbolicConstant Ok. When discussing vendor specific performance matters, (mysql), mentionning others is usually irrelevant. I removed the sql-server and php tags to not confuse the audience. Thanks for the detailed question though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with a single `LEFT JOIN` and `SUM(CASE WHEN...END)`:

```
CREATE TABLE reviews(
    id          INT,
    review_id   VARCHAR(10),
    review      VARCHAR(10)
)
CREATE TABLE review_counts(
    id          INT,
    review_id   VARCHAR(10),
    votes       INT
)
INSERT INTO reviews VALUES
(1, 'review1', 'Review 1'),
(2, 'review2', 'Review 2');
INSERT INTO review_counts VALUES
(1, 'Review1', 1),
(2, 'Review1', 1),
(3, 'Review1', 1),
(4, 'Review1', 1),
(5, 'Review1', 1),
(6, 'Review2', -1),
(7, 'Review2', -1),
(8, 'Review2', -1),
(9, 'Review2', -1),
(10, 'Review2', -1);

SELECT
    r.*,
    SUM(CASE WHEN c.votes = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Vote_Up,
    SUM(CASE WHEN c.votes = -1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Vote_Down
FROM reviews r
LEFT JOIN review_counts c
    ON c.review_id = r.review_id
GROUP BY r.id, r.review_id, r.review

DROP TABLE reviews
DROP TABLE review_counts
```

**RESULT**

```
id          review_id  review     Vote_Up     Vote_Down
----------- ---------- ---------- ----------- -----------
1           review1    Review 1   5           0
2           review2    Review 2   0           5
```

Comment: Yup, this is what i wanted, I just changed the case statement from `r.votes=1` to `c.votes=1` as my review table does not have `votes` column and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: I was going through the query, problem is that I am getting only one result. here is a screenshot [http://i.imgur.com/tbD7sO1.png](http://i.imgur.com/tbD7sO1.png).  The 7 down votes are on the second review, but query shows it for the first review itself.